# Source Tree connecting to VSTS GIT Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights

Tags: git, azure-devops, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm Trying to connect to VSTS Online GIT via SourceTree i get following error. Funny thing is VisualStudio 2017 and GIt bash could connect to the repo without issues. What's wrong with SourceTree setup??

git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch --prune --tags origin
FATAL ERROR: Server sent disconnect message
type 2 (protocol error):
"Invalid packet"
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Completed with errors, see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real issue was there is a outbound proxy stop communication in cycles. Sometimes work sometimes dont. fix was to

#

```
 Get system value 
$ git config --system --get https.proxy 
$ git config --system --get http.proxy 

# Get global value
 $ git config --global --get https.proxy
 $ git config --global --get http.proxy
```

explained here

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/can-t-clone-or-pull-due-to-a-git-outbound-proxy-779171769.html

Answer (score 1):

It’s mainly caused by the VSTS authentication has not restored in SourceTree.

You can double check by clicking Tools -> Options -> Authentication Tab -> check if your VSTS account has been restored password.

[image]

If not, you should clone a VSTS git repo by SourceTree at first. Then SourceTree will recognize that you are authorized to operate the VSTS git repo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply in my case it was a proxy issue i had to add the proxy to global got config